# How to pull specific version of Docker Postgres Image?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am new to docker area. I did docker pull postgres and docker pull postgres:9.5.4 , in both cases it pulling latest image as postgres 10.1 (see below).

PostgreSQL 10.1 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit

I would like to pull only 9.5.4 version of postgres image from dockers hub.

[image: Even pulled 9.5.4 or 9.5.10 showing always postgres 10.1]
[image: postgres 9.5.4]
[image: postgres 9.5.10]

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/ and check out the page for the image if it supports the requested tag... AFAIK 9.5.10 is supported @ https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

Comment: How did you generate the version line you included in your question?

Comment: added screens hots !

Comment: `docker pull != docker run`. How are you running it?

Comment: docker start postgres ( its like first docker-machine v5  is up, and then in that v5 postgres

Answer (score 18):

Based on your screenshots, you seem to think that pulling `postgres:9.5.10` followed by `docker start postgres` will run the thing you just pulled. This is incorrect - it's restarting an older container that had previously run on your system.

Try this:

```
docker run postgres:9.5.10
```

Comment: But I deleted existing image from docker rmi image-name before that doing it, an dnow when I do the run , it suck here :/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*

..LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped

PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-01-10 23:02:18 UTC
LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started

Comment: `LOG: database system is ready to accept connections` That looks like it successfully started. If you want the command to return, use `docker run -d postgres:9.5.10` to keep the container running in the background.